# Does anyone know why Scene Builder is stuck when processing an import?

Tags: scenebuilder, gluon

I've tried a hundred times to import the charm.glisten-library from gluon, but Scene Builder always keeps getting stuck at 9%. Does anybody have the same issue? And does anyone know an answer? I would really like to start with gluon, but I can't because of the issue...

[image: Scene Builder Importing]

Comment: I've just tried now and it works fine for me with `com.gluonhq:charm-glisten:4.1.0`. But I recall having your issue once. Just click `OK` to stop the process, and your controls should be imported. You can verify it clicking on the edit button and make sure the controls are there.

Comment: Yes, I know. But I think that not all of the components are loaded succesfully when the counter gets stuck at 9%. I think it's Windows who is showing it's capacities, a friend with a Macbook does not have this issue. But by next week, I'll get my own Macbook, so let's hope it'll work on the Macbook... Thanks for your support!

Comment: Recently I bought a Mac and there everything seems to work fine. So, I'm very happy with that...